# Office 2008 in native languages

Tags: language, ms-office, internationalization

I can't find how to buy it, so I assumed that on English is available.

Does anyone know if there are other languages available for this product, or like in Windows version a Profiling Tools that not only change the GUI locale but also adds the dictionaries in that language.

I'm currently searching the Portuguese version for a friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Office 2008 for Mac is [available in the following languages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2275307):

- Danish (as part of the Nordic Pack)
- Dutch
- English
- Finnish (as part of the Nordic Pack)
- French
- German
- Italian
- Japanese
- Norwegian (as part of the Nordic Pack)
- Spanish
- Swedish

Office 2011 added Russian and Polish to this list.

I know that for Office 2008, the CD contained only one language, so it's not like other Mac applications that ship with all languages and change based on your system language settings.

Comment: That is correct, my brother has a Spanish version of Office 2008 for Mac

Answer (score 3):

Office 2008 ships with a Portugese (and a Brazilian alternative) proofing tool as part of the package.

Source: [Microsoft's list of proofing tools](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/itpros/default.mspx?clr=99-15-0&srcid=73264c8f-de1a-41c6-b40a-b9376c5aa62f1033&ep=9&target=6474a4a6-9d3e-4bde-a255-fb9286ef5d101033&CTT=InContent)

Comment: this is only Proofing Tools, this does not change the GUI. But thank you for pointing me that this part is already shipped with the Office.